# Please help identify this fern

Tags: identification, ferns

I've been having real trouble identifying this fern. Anyone with good knowledge of ferns out there know what it is? I would very much like to know.

Photographed in Yamaguchi, Japan.

[image: Unidentified fern]

[image: Location]

Comment: Do you have other pictures?  These are obviously young fern leaves, not the mature form.  Where in Japan?

Comment: This is on the outskirts of Mine, Yamaguchi Prefecture, Japan. It's in the far west of the main island of Honshu. In a thinly forested area next to a stream at the foot of the mountains, elevation 84 m (34°13'39" N 131°18'15" E). Photo taken in late August.

Comment: I only took a couple of photos, they're at the same angle. None of the underside or base. But I'll include one here from further back—as soon as I figure out how to add another photo.

Comment: I see. I went back and added to the original post to get the photo in.

Comment: Only the single larger fern seen at the top/rear of the second bottom photo may be the same plant as the frond from the original close-up photo (top photo).  The other somewhat smaller ferns (in the foreground of the bottom photo) look much like Dryopteris filix-mas which is a common Wood fern found in Japan. The other (top photo) fern could be the same genus though, but not enough detail/characteristics in the photos to say for sure.

Comment: I used to have friends in Japan I would have asked.  Do you live in Japan?  Lucky lucky you if so.  What an amazing country and amazing people.  I grew up in Japan, aregato! Or is it arigato?  You should try contacting the equivalent University Cooperative Extension Service we have here in the States.  There are different stages of fern leaves on all plants.  Add to that, having lots of sun, the leaves are tighter and smaller.  If the fern is in deep deep shade the leaves will be broader, overlapping some times.  If you are able, we would love to know the answer.  Thanks!  Or, domo aregato!

Comment: Yes, I live here in Japan. Right, it's arigato. Well, I'd like to be able to contact some experts here but I'm not even sure where to start. If anyone else here had some ideas, please let me know!

Answer (score 2):

[image: Cinnamon Fern]  This is one possibility. The Cinnamon fern.  Were you in North or South Japan?  High elevations or sea level?

These are actually older fronds of the Cinnamon Fern.
[image: cinnamon fern]

[image: closer image of mature Cinnamon Fern]

I've also looked at Deer and Hard Fern as possibilities...

Comment: Good point about the maturity of the frond. I wasn't aware that they might change (just getting into learning about ferns here). This frond seems very distinctive, with large spaces between the alternating pinnae and curved, dagger-like pinnules. This fern would be 1-pinnate-pinnatifid? Perhaps in the more mature form, the pinnules become rounder and less like curved daggers?

I think we can rule out deer fern because of the differing frond structure.

Comment: Very nice, Biscut.  You are able to 'see'!  We'll be back, soon or someone on our team shall be! Ferns and grasses are tough to ID/

Answer (score 2):

[image: Cinnamon Fern]  This is one possibility. The Cinnamon fern.  Were you in North or South Japan?  High elevations or sea level?